# API-запрос к сайту и запись JSON ответа

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, xml, api

коллеги. Только начал изучать БД. Прошу объяснить как можно проще.

Столкнулся с тем что не могу найти нигде решение следующей задачи:

нужно из БД отправить api-запрос к внешнему сайту, получить ответ в виде JSON или XML (который возвращает сайт), распарсить этот JSON или XML-ответ в таблицу и сохранить его в БД. API открытый и регистрации на сайте не трубуется достаточно ввести ссылку в браузере.

[http://iss.moex.com/iss/history/engines/stock/markets/shares/boards/tqbr/securities.json?date=2022-06-17][1]

[http://iss.moex.com/iss/history/engines/stock/markets/shares/boards/tqbr/securities.xml?date=2022-06-17][2]

Я прекрано понимаю что есть реализация с помощью других инструментов, но я хотел бы понять можно ли инструментами sql сделать эту задачу.

Спасибо.

Comment: В самом sql и в pl/pgsql таких стредств нет. Можно использовать расширения типа [plpython](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html), но в этом случае собственно код все равно будет на питоне и делать это в БД - это масса неудобств при сомнительной пользе, в большинстве случаев будет гораздо лучше делать это внешней программой на питоне, которая просто будет сохранять данные в БД, если так нужно.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Буду думать.